# How to efficiently find nearest date before and after a reference date in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with the following columns: user ID, reference date, date of event, event value.

- User IDs are unique, and there are multiple entries for each ID
- Reference date is unique to each user ID

I want to find the indices of the events that happen closest to the reference date, **both before and after**.

Example:

| user_id | reference_date | event_date | event_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2021-05-15 | 2020-09-02 | 10 |
| 1234 | 2021-05-15 | 2021-04-28 | 15 |
| 1234 | 2021-05-15 | 2021-06-01 | 11 |

The code should return something like

| user_id | reference_date | event_1 | value_1 | event_2 | value_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2021-05-15 | 2021-04-28 | 15 | 2021-06-01 | 11 |

Comment: Why is event 11 selected when event 15 is also 17 days away?

Comment: @It_is_Chris I'm looking for the closest event_date in both directions of the reference_date

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it using a `merge_asof` statement while setting the `direction` argument to the `nearest`, like this:

```
df_merged = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on=['user_id'], direction='nearest')
```

Just before that, ensure that your dates are in date format using:

```
df['reference_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['reference_date'])
df['event_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_date'])
```

So, to have it as a whole in the context, the code should look like this:

```
import pandas as pd

my_dict = {'user_id':[1234, 1234, 1234], \
           'reference_date':['2021-05-15', '2021-05-15', '2021-05-15'], \
           'event_date':['2020-09-02', '2021-04-28', '2021-06-01'], \
           'event_value':[10, 15, 11]}

df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
df['reference_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['reference_date'])
df['event_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_date'])

df1 = df[['user_id','reference_date']]
df2 = df[['user_id','reference_date','event_date','event_value']]


df_merged = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on=['user_id'], direction='nearest')
df_merged = df_merged.drop_duplicates(subset=['user_id'])
print(df_merged)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# Sample data but added an additonal group
s = """user_id,reference_date,event_date,event_value
1234,2021-05-15,2020-09-02,10
1234,2021-05-15,2021-04-28,15
1234,2021-05-15,2021-06-01,11
12346,2021-05-20,2021-09-02,10
12346,2021-05-20,2021-06-28,15
12346,2021-05-20,2021-06-01,11"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s))

# convert dates to datetime
df['reference_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['reference_date'])
df['event_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['event_date'])

# Filter your df using loc 
# Calculate the difference between the reference and event date
# groupby and get the index of the min values using idxmin
df.loc[df.assign(diff=abs(df[['reference_date',
                                'event_date']].diff(axis=1)['event_date']))\
       .groupby(['user_id', 'reference_date'])['diff'].idxmin()]

   user_id reference_date event_date  event_value
1     1234     2021-05-15 2021-04-28           15
5    12346     2021-05-20 2021-06-01           11
```

If you want to keep all the min values and not just the first occurrence then use groupby with transform

```
d = df.assign(diff=abs(df[['reference_date', 'event_date']].diff(axis=1)['event_date']))
df[d['diff'] == d.groupby(['user_id', 'reference_date'])['diff'].transform(min)]

   user_id reference_date event_date  event_value
1     1234     2021-05-15 2021-04-28           15
2     1234     2021-05-15 2021-06-01           11
5    12346     2021-05-20 2021-06-01           11
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fcl(df, dtObj):
    return df.iloc[np.argmin(np.abs(df.index.to_pydatetime() - dtObj))]
```

**ArgMin** finds the global minimum of f subject.

So this just returns an element, which has the minimum difference between 2 dates.

This function returns the closest date in df, where **dtObj** - is that date.

---

For use in your case:

```
def fcl(df, columnName, dtObj):
    return df.iloc[np.argmin(np.abs(df[columnName] - dtObj))]

date = "2021-02-15"
date = pd.to_datetime(date)

test = fcl(df,'reference_date', date)
```

of course, the dtObject can be columnName argument or event_date - like here:

```
def fcl(df, columnName, dtObj):
    return df.iloc[np.argmin(np.abs(df[columnName] - df['event_date']))]
```

output:

[image]